# How to translate the projected object in screen in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I've rendered an 3d object and its 2d projection in the image is correct. However now I want to shift the 2d projected object by some pixels. How do I achieve that?

Note that simply translating the 3d object doesn't work because under perspective projection the 2d projected object could change. My goal is to just shift the 2d object in the image without changing its shape and size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the programmable pipeline, you can apply the translation after you applied the projection transformation.

The only thing you have to be careful about is that the transformed coordinates after applying the projection matrix have a `w` coordinate that will be used for the perspective division. To make the additional translation amount constant in screen space, you'll have to multiply it by `w`. The key fragments of the vertex shader would look like this:

```
in vec4 Position;
uniform mat4 ModelViewProjMat;
uniform vec2 TranslationOffset;

void main() {
    gl_Position = ModelViewProjMat * Position;
    gl_Position.xy += TranslationOffset * gl_Position.w;
}
```

After the perspective division by `w`, this will result in a fixed offset.

Another possibility that works with both the programmable and fixed pipeline is that you shift the viewport. Say if the window size is `vpWidth` times `vpHeight`, and the offset you want to apply is `(xOffset, yOffset)`, you can set the viewport to:

```
glViewport(xOffset, yOffset, vpWidth + xOffset, vpHeight + yOffset);
```

One caveat here is that the geometry will still be clipped by the same view volume, but only be shifted by the viewport transform after clipping was applied. If the geometry would fit completely inside the original viewport, this will work fine. But if the geometry would have been clipped originally, it will still be clipped with the same planes, even though it might actually be inside the window after the shift is applied.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast reply. If I understand correctly, the gl_Position here is the 3d coordinates in the camera coordinate system after transformation. However, the object I drew was actually a teapot(using glutSolidTeapot) and I transformed it using glTranslatef and glRotatef. Could you tell me how to get the gl_Position of the teapot?

Comment: The first proposed solution can be used if you use the programmable pipeline. This means that you write your own shaders in GLSL. This gives you much more flexibility on how transformations are applied. It sounds like you're using the legacy fixed pipeline? I can try and add something about using that solution with the fixed pipeline. The second solution, which modifies the viewport, should work in either case.

Comment: Thank you so much Reto! The second solution works great for me!

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to Reto Koradi's answer: You don't need shaders and you don't need to modify the viewport you use (which has the clipping issues mentioned in the answer). You can simply modifiy the projection matrix by *pre-multiplying* some translation (which in effect will be applied last, after the projective transformation):

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranstlate(x,y,z); // <- this one was added
glFrustum(...) or gluPerspective(...) or whatever you use
```

`glFrustum` and `gluPerspective` will multiply the current matrix with the projective transfrom matrix they build, that is why one typically loads identity first. However, it doesn't necessarily have to be identity, and this case is one of the rare cases where one should load something else.

Since you want to shift in pixels, but that transformation is applied in clip space, you need some unit conversions. Since the clip space is just the homogenous representation of the normalized device space, where the frustum is [-1,1] in all 3 dimensions (so the viewport is 2x2 units big in that space), you can use the following:

```
glTranslate(x * 2.0f/viewport_width, y * 2.0f/viewport_height, 0.0f);
```

to shift the output by `(x,y)` pixels.

Note that while I wrote this for fixed-function GL, the math will of course work with shaders as well, and you can simply modify the projection matrix used by the shader in the same way.

Comment: The viewport can extend outside the window, so that part is not a problem. But anyway, I initially thought that simply adding a translation to the projection matrix would not work because of what happens during the perspective division later. After writing down the matrices, it indeed looks like it should work just fine.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: You're right about the viewport, I removed that errant claim.