# Translate a shape by x screen pixels without modifying viewport

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am using OpenGLES 2.0 to render a simple 3D scene with a cube. So far, this part works like a charm. 
**Basic idea:** Now, I would like to be able to draw a second cube, translated by *50 pixels* on the x-axis. How can I achieve this without touching the viewport ?

**Context:** I want to achieve a stereo effect with binocular AR glasses. These glasses use side-by-side 3D, meaning it just splits the screen in two, send the left part to the left eye and the right part to the right eye. Therefore, I was thinking of using two viewports, one for each half. However, I need to apply some additionnal pixel translation to the cube before drawing it within the second viewport. How can I do that ?

**Example:** Imagine I have a screen of 1280*720 pixels. The first cube is now at position (100,y,z) on the screen. I update the viewport to draw on the right part of the screen (which starts at 640 in x), then I want to draw the second cube. However, I don't want to draw it at position (100, y, z) within this new viewport, but at position (50, y, z).

**What I have tried:** second answer of [this Stack Overflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018458/how-to-translate-the-projected-object-in-screen-in-opengl), but the translation does not seem to have any effect. And since the value of the pixel translation I would like to do is constantly varying, I am not sure the first approach proposed (with the shader) is suitable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The shader based approach with a translation offset is definitely the right answer. Vertex animation is the entire point of the vertex shader after all ...

Comment: Note that for VR/AR you need more than just a simple 2D translation between the two eyes - the brain interprets the scene as true 3D because the 3D projection is seen from a slightly different camera position.

Comment: You are right about the shader approach, it was the simplest way to do it in the end. I just had to become a little bit more familiar with it and it went smoothly. Thanks for the advice about AR and camera position, I will apply it.